# TabHost and ActionBar

Tags: android

I am creating an android application that have three tabs using `TabHost` and `TabSpec`.
The problem is when i enable `Holo.Light.DarkActionBar` the actionbar appears below to the tabs.
Here is my code

```
TabHost.TabSpec homespec=tabhost.newTabSpec("Home");
homespec.setIndicator("Home",null);
Intent homeintent=new Intent(this,HomeActivity.class);
homespec.setContent(homeintent);

TabHost.TabSpec eventspec=tabhost.newTabSpec("Event");
eventspec.setIndicator("Event");
Intent eventintent=new Intent(this,EventActivity.class);
eventspec.setContent(eventintent);

TabHost.TabSpec profilespec=tabhost.newTabSpec("Profile");
profilespec.setIndicator("Profile");
Intent profileintent=new Intent(this,ProfileActivity.class);
profilespec.setContent(profileintent);

tabhost.addTab(homespec);
tabhost.addTab(eventspec);
tabhost.addTab(profilespec);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the theme of classes of HomeActivity,EventActivity and profileActivity to Theme.Holo.light.NoActionBar

Comment: Thanks Dillip it works after changing the class to normal activity

Answer (score 2):

Hi I found the answer finally.The problem is that I had extend my `HomeActivity,EventActivity,ProfileActivity` classes with `ActionBarActivity`.
After Changing,it to normal `Activity` works perfectly.